# SIMD programming: "mode 'V4SF' applied to inappropriate type" error

Tags: c

I am trying to use SIMD instructions in my C program. I am using CodeBlocks to write in.

I tried following this tutorial: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/geoff/cell/ps3-linux-docs/CellProgrammingTutorial/BasicsOfSIMDProgramming.html

I am trying to do both integer and floating point SIMD addition, subtraction, etc.

However, the code explained in the page does not work in CodeBlocks/C. How do I use SIMD here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int v4sf __attribute__ ((mode(V4SF))); // vector of four single floats

union f4vector
{
  v4sf v;
  float f[4];
};
int main()
{
  union f4vector a, b, c;

  a.f[0] = 1; a.f[1] = 2; a.f[2] = 3; a.f[3] = 4;
  b.f[0] = 5; b.f[1] = 6; b.f[2] = 7; b.f[3] = 8;

  c.v = a.v + b.v;

  printf("%f, %f, %f, %f\n", c.f[0], c.f[1], c.f[2], c.f[3]);
}
```

```
C:\Things\New Text Document.c|2|warning: specifying vector types with __attribute__ ((mode)) is deprecated [-Wattributes]|
C:\Things\New Text Document.c|2|warning: use __attribute__ ((vector_size)) instead [-Wattributes]|
C:\Things\New Text Document.c|2|error: mode 'V4SF' applied to inappropriate type|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: CodeBlocks is as relevant as the brand of keyboard you are using to type the code. What is relevant? The code. Show your code, together with any errors you are getting.

Comment: I am using the code in the tutorial. Specifically, "Solution Program (2-1)"

The error I am getting is right away that 



  "__vector signed int va    = (__vector signed int) { 1, 2, 3, 4 };"



is not recognized as trying to define any variables.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know. Well the first problem I get is that the IDE doesnt recognize my statement as trying to define a SIMD set of variables. The desired behavior is that they are properly defined, and then I can use them to be added to other SIMD sets.

Comment: Show (as opposed to "talk about")  your code and the errors you are getting in the question itself. Click the "edit" link and paste the code and the compiler messages in the box.

Comment: I edited my main post to reflect the code. Its a little messy as Im not used to how the coding markup works here ':)

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you are trying to use is for SIMD programming for the Cell CPU (i.e, in the Playstation 3). It is not applicable to x86 programming.

Use a tutorial that is applicable to the compiler you are using (GCC, Clang, or Visual C++).

Comment: You were right, I didn't notice that. 

So I went and looked up a tutorial for GCC (as CodeBlocks uses GCC) using this tutorial: http://ds9a.nl/gcc-simd/example.html

I just plain copy and pasted exactly what he did in the first two code blocks in the correct order and then got these errors:

(added to main op)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your CPU supports the vector type intrinsics and vector instructions you want to use before you compile and/or execute.

I'm guessing your CPU is x86, but Windows should have a way to verify that.  With Linux you can run something like `grep avx2  /proc/cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

the tuition has something wrong that the typedef origin date type should be the float.

For a compile through example is as follow

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef float v4sf __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

union f4vector
{
    v4sf v;
    float f[4];
};

int main()
{
    union f4vector a, b, c;

    a.f[0] = 1; a.f[1] = 2; a.f[2] = 3; a.f[3] = 4;
    b.f[0] = 5; b.f[1] = 6; b.f[2] = 7; b.f[3] = 8;

    c.v = a.v + b.v;

    printf("%f, %f, %f, %f\n", c.f[0], c.f[1], c.f[2], c.f[3]);
}
```